# Swagger Autogeneration: Generating Generic types from swagger document | openapi: 3.0.0

Tags: java, generics, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am autogenerating my models using Swagger autogen tool.
I am trying to create a generic type for a member variable. In the example below I am trying to create a generic value `generiValue`for my employee class.

```
public class Employee<T> implements Comparable<Employee<T>> {
    @NotEmpty
    Long id;
    @NotBlank
    String employeeName;
    @NotNull
    T genericValue;

}
```

This is my `swagger.yaml`:

```
Employee:
  type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      employeeName:
        type: "string"
        format: "string"        
      genericValue:
        type: generic
```

Is it possible to create a generic variable or is it not supported in swagger autogeneration?

I tried to do using `AnyValue`

```
components:
  schemas:
    AnyValue: {}
```

but the code is not generated for Java in Generic form.

Note that I am using OpenAPI version 3.0.0.